# Find the optimal number of samples using sub-sampling

Tags: sample-size

I want to run a simulation where I determine what the optimal number of samples are to derive a reliable estimate.

Suppose I conducted a pilot experiment where I measured the average of user ratings for different products. For each product I collected data from 20 users.

Now I want to run a simulation where I determine whether I can obtain similar ratings if I only were to obtain ratings from 5 or 10 or 15 people.

I have thought of several approaches to run this simulation but was wondering if there was a standard approach.

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are asking, because subsampling is not bootstrapping.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Then I mean subsampling with replacement.

Comment: Importantly (for this application) does it make more sense to sample with or without replacement?

Comment: That is an interesting question.  I find it helpful to contemplate the case where you are considering a sample that is only slightly smaller, such as 18, 19, or 20 people: there would be little variation in the results if you sampled without replacement.  A good search term is "plug-in principle."